In case \newgeometry is used, width of the awesomebox boxes reduced each time they are used
The following MCE points out a strange behavior of awesomeboxes in case a new geometry of the page is used: their width is reduced each time they are used.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{margin=1cm}

\begin{document}
Foo.

\newgeometry{margin=2cm}

\importantbox{\lipsum[1]}

\importantbox{\lipsum[1]}

\importantbox{\lipsum[1]}

\importantbox{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}


Do you understand what's going on?

The logic in \awesomeboxadjustcontentwidth and \awesomeboxrestorecontentwidth is wrong. The first tests if \linewidth equals \aweboxlinewidthref, which after \newgeometry they are not, but the second checks if \linewidth equals \textwidth and does not restore \aweboxcontentwidth if so

@mbert The attention of the author of awesomebox is drawn.

awesomeboxes uses the length \aweboxlinewidthref to adjust and restore awesome boxes content width. This length is set to \linewidth through the hook begindocument.
This lenght isn't updated if you change the geometry after the preamble, so awesomeboxes is lost. The reduction, at each use, is caused by \awesomeboxadjustcontentwidth witch recompute the value of \aweboxcontentwidth if the current \linewidth differs from the saved one. Look at its definition:
\newcommand{\awesomeboxadjustcontentwidth}{%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\linewidth=\aweboxlinewidthref}}{}{%
    \setlength{\aweboxlinewidthvar}{\dimexpr\aweboxlinewidthref-\linewidth}%
    \setlength{\aweboxcontentwidth}{\dimexpr\aweboxcontentwidth-\aweboxlinewidthvar}}}%
    %\aweboxdebug}}

So, apart of setting the geometry in the preamble only, you can reset all awesomeboxes lengths that are defined at the beginning of the document. Add after \newgeometry:
\setlength{\aweboxleftmargin}{0.12\linewidth}%
\setlength{\aweboxcontentwidth}{0.88\linewidth}
\setlength{\aweboxlinewidthref}{\linewidth}


Unfortunately, I can't rely on \AtBeginDocument since I need a specific geometry of the page at the beginning of the document (for the title page) and another one for the subsequent pages. But adding these lines after the \newgeometry does the trick (I tried to do something like this but only for \aweboxcontentwidth which wasn't enough). Could you edit your answer in order I can accept it?

@DenisBitouzé I didn't mean you should reset the lengths with \AtBeginDocument but you should reset the lengths that have been initially set with AtBebinDocument. I edited the answer. I hope it's clearer now.

Thank you very much for the insights on the subject. I must admit I didn’t think about this when I wrote this part of the code. I’ll try to improve it and release a new version. If anyone of you is able to send me a patch in the mean time, it will be warmly welcomed!

@Étienne You could maybe replace \aweboxlinewidthref with \columnwidth, it hold the width of the text area.
